# displaying input field in USD currency format

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text field which is getting diaplayed from database as a number i.e., 1234567. I want to display that number as USD currency format i.e.,$1,234,567.Can anyone help me out please...my HTML code is..

```
<html>
<td>gettingfromdatabase.price</td>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this using Javascript:

```
function handleChange() {
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (x.indexOf("$") != 0)
    {
        x = "$" + x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    document.getElementById("name").value = x;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VSuvA/15/)**

Comment: Thanks for the information.But what about the commas?? i mean my format should be like $1,234,567. and I dont want it onblur.I want that format as soon as my page loads.

Comment: @sheela:- See the edit! And you can use this logic on the page load. I have just provided you the logic! Hope that helps!

Comment: the above code is working for input tag not for span. I want that for span. Do you have any idea??   <td><span id="testing" data-bind="text: SPL_ApprovalDetailsObj.TgtSales "/></td>

Comment: @sheela:- Could you please another question for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript! Have a function that doing it!

```
<script>
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(places, symbol, thousand, decimal) {
    places = !isNaN(places = Math.abs(places)) ? places : 2;
    symbol = symbol !== undefined ? symbol : "$";
    thousand = thousand || ",";
    decimal = decimal || ".";
    var number = this, 
        negative = number < 0 ? "-" : "",
        i = parseInt(number = Math.abs(+number || 0).toFixed(places), 10) + "",
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return symbol + negative + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousand : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=

\d)/g, "$1" + thousand) + (places ? decimal + Math.abs(number - i).toFixed(places).slice(2) : "");
};

var total = 4555;
console.log(total.formatMoney());

</script>
```

Then you set total.formatMoney() where you want! where is `console.log(total.formatMoney());` you set a object or field.

If it was a field `document.getElementById('objectID').innerHTML= total.formatMoney();`, you can use a span, div, set in `('objectID')`.

Comment: The example up writte output: `$4,555.00`

Comment: @ Rogerio de Moraes Can you please tell how to use the above in sapn tag                                                                   <td><span id="testing" data-bind="text:SPL_ApprovalDetailsObj.TgtSales "/></td>

Comment: `Use document.getElementById('testing').innerHTML= total.formatMoney();`
put below function within the tag.

Ex.: 
`document.getElementById('testing').innerHTML= total.formatMoney();
</script>`